# Allow for Area 51-like mini-metas per documentation tag

Tags: feature-request, documentation

#### The issue

Ultimately it looks like comments on topic proposals and change proposals are just not *enough*. They're not a platform for general tag-specific discussion.

Currently we come to meta, but especially in smaller tags, chances are (large) that people miss the meta discussion (either because they're not really invested in meta or because of all the other noise or just not check all day). Thus, long-term, this is not a viable solution. [and probably generating much noise for the not interested ones here on MSO.]

See also the related discussion here on this meta:

[Where can we discuss guidelines for Documentation on a per-tag basis?](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/329173/where-can-we-discuss-guidelines-for-documentation-on-a-per-tag-basis)

#### Suggested solution

It'd be really helpful to be able to discuss documentation tag-specific actions (defining scope, planning how to reorganize, etc.) on **the individual tags in some sort of a mini-meta**.

As we all know, Area 51 has discussions which are integrated into the main site inside the individual tags. Exactly this same concept I'm referencing here for tag discussions.

How exactly this is implemented (e.g. an automatic tag `documentation-tag-<tagname>` on this meta and then proxied to the main site), is irrelevant here and up to the developers.

Comment: This would make it a lot easier to work here comfortably again. I failed with [this proposal](http://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/328654/let-documentation-having-its-own-meta-site) at least.

Comment: @πάνταῥεῖ Your proposal is vastly different though. You proposed a wholly separate meta site for _all_ of documentation, which, IMO, rightfully has been rejected. I propose just a discussion platform for tag-specific issues. Which is much more specific and usually not interesting for the broad public / community managers.

Comment: Related to http://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/329173/

Comment: There is clearly demand for such a discussion place. It should be part of the dashboard.

Comment: Here's an example of this spilling over on to meta: http://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/328937/

Comment: @Frank good example… should definitely be in such a discussion instead.

Comment: And another: http://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/332590/

Answer (score 14):

Yes. We need this.

I think this could be an extension to the flag/improvement feature to signal what you are referring to.

I think it would be a nice thing to have different views on docs, at least one to just read it and another one with the meta discussion attached for editing. Seeing the discussed example next to the meta discussion side by side on a wide screen would be a neat addition.

This might also solve the access problem: *Who's allowed to edit things?* answer: nobody by default. Every suggested edit becomes a new discussion in the associated meta and only with a given number of up votes there can it be applied.… or something along those lines, just a spontaneous idea.

Comment: In theory slow collaboration leads to a bit better, it is a motivation killer to some extent too. I would not go _too_ far in slowing it down. I'd rather see the current review process improved instead

Comment: You can already comment on suggested edits.

Answer (score 8):

I was just thinking about how similar Documentation is to Wikipedia, and I had a similar idea.

On every Wikipedia page, there is a link to a [talk page](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Help:Using_talk_pages). I think that we can learn a lot from what they have there.

I think that having it on a per-tag basis only may make things prohibitively hard to find. We already have problems with organization as it is, so we should avoid making things worse.

I think that a format similar to Wikipedia would be good. It's very organized, with a link to [talk] on each (non-talk) page. That way, we would always know what exactly is being discussed.

Obviously, it should also be possible to list all the discussions within a tag. We already have a similar thing with edits and improvement requests, and a similar thing would work for this feature.

My current thought is that this feature will be a more advanced form of improvement requests, visible from both the complete list:

> [image]

and also the topic they belong to:

> [image]

Comment: This is a great point. However, you also need a way to track the discussions per tag, else a discussion is started and the next reply comes a fortnight later when the next one sees it. Additionally there still needs to be discussions which are generally applicable for a tag (e.g. questions on scope of a tag). So, I think, it would be preferable if the discussions were still per-tag and can be tied to a topic or even example (so that there is a link on the topic page to a list of discussions of that topic/the topics examples).

Comment: While they haven't told us, I think the devs made a deliberate decision not to have talk pages, to prevent people from asking and answering questions there that belonged on SO.  Having a meta-like organization would allow such questions to be migrated (and [Q&A that are about Docs errors can be moved there](http://meta.stackoverflow.com/a/330190/3614835)).

Comment: @JeffreyBosboom I have been running into things that I's like clarification on, but I'm not sure if asking a question on SO is truly appropriate. It's also the type of thing that I would vote as "not meta enough"

Comment: Yes, the improvement request system could actually be designed as an implicit question, while allowing for comments… yea, that could work out…

Comment: I don't think the Wikipedia Talk page works very well. It's okay for page specific issues (the comments here) but the whole meta level we have here on SO is totally missing on Wikipedia (or difficult to find anyway). I like that I have one place (meta) where I can discuss many different things (specific or general). The tag level seems like the right place.

Comment: @Trilarion I don't actually contribute to Wikipedia, so I'm not sure exactly what you mean. Can you elaborate?

Comment: @Laurel I also contributed to Wikipedia only in a few cases. I just mean the Talk pages that you also mean. They are limited in scope. I like Meta on SO much more because it centralizes many discussion, which is in my opinion much more powerful.

Comment: @Trilarion Aren't meta questions limited in scope too?

Comment: @Laurel Sure, the scope would however be greater then, wouldn't it. As I understood this question and your answer the difference would be the scope. bwoebi wants a tag-wide scope, you want a topic-wide scope. Maybe I made a mistake there?

Comment: @Trilarion I've added some pictures to show you what I mean. Does it make more sense now?