# Are questions whose research is primarily based on Documentation on-topic?

Tags: discussion, documentation, asking-questions

I just hypothesized a new category of questions on Stack Overflow, whose research primarily consists of information obtained from reading Documentation for a given topic. (There is an Ask Question button at the end of every topic page that *strongly* encourages this, even if that was not the use case it was designed for.) Let's set aside the debate of whether such questions should be downvoted because the author didn't bother to cross-reference with official sources for a second.

Given the *very* pliable nature of Documentation, what should be done with such questions in the event that the answer is "that Documentation example is wrong" and a change correcting the example gets proposed (and, hopefully, approved), thus rendering the question obsolete? Should the question then be closed as "resolved in a manner unlikely to help future readers"? Or should the question be kept around on the presumption that if the factually incorrect information was approved for Documentation in the first place then enough people have been misled by this misinformation that

- the answer to such a question would benefit those people, and
- someone else might propose the same misinformation *back* into the Documentation topic at a later date and someone else might approve it again? (And you thought incorrect answers on Q&A was bad...)

Comment: Ugh, that should really be a "search more" button.

Comment: Let's treat this case as every other case of "the documentation somewhere is wrong" which means that the question is meaningful and should stay open at least until the documentation is fixed.

Answer (score 16):

Such a question should be migrated to the [hypothetical mini meta](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/329686/4347580) of the relevant tag, where it should be treated like an improvement request.

Comment: I like how you allude to a hypothetical feature in your answer to my question about a hypothetical category of questions.

Comment: And that the linked answer is his own.