# Documentation is on its way to becoming the next W3Schools

Tags: discussion, documentation, edits

#### Motivation:

> I only posted this because I have seen complaints from others about
>   the exact same type of behavior in multiple tags.

I was able to participate in the non-public documentation period.

I added a few examples that I am intimately familiar with that are basic things that get asked over and over on the main site in preparation to be able to link to them.

Once the documentation feature went public my examples were mutilated and vandalized by people that were not qualified to make changes to them to the point that they are now completely incorrect. This implies that even more people that were not competent to judge the changes approved them.

These changes all were considered *"stylistic"* changes, but they also broke the semantics of the code because the editor(s)/approver(s) had no concept of what `final` does to local variables in [java](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/java).

#### Here is a description of one of the examples that I requested to be deleted:

<sub>I did not want to link to the specific example because I did not want it edited or un-deleted or *fixed*, I just don't want to be associated with it any more. But I did end up posting one because a mod requested it.</sub>

I found the original example that I am referring to [here](https://stackoverflow.com/documentation/java/596/jdbc/1940/properly-closing-resources-before-java-7#t=2016050922102335). I am not sure if anyone can see that link, but that is how the example started, I think you can see the edit history is a mess and why I gave up; just look at what I contributed and the last edit to see [what a complete mess of it devolved into](https://stackoverflow.com/documentation/review/changes/30976).

I had an example that showed how to properly close JDBC resources pre-1.7.

The code uses the `final` keyword to ensure that the references are immutable and by doing so completely eliminates the need to test for `null`, because the resource reference is either created successfully or an exception is thrown.

This means that the `try/catch/finally` block can skip the `null` check and just call `.close()`, because it is guaranteed that the reference can never be `null`.

Multiple people edited and re-edited the `try/catch/finally` blocks into a single method that the reference was passed into to *eliminate duplicate code*. Well, this also completely removes the guarantees that my code afforded.

After reverting and explaining to stop approving these edits multiple times I just gave up and requested the example and others that were suffering similar fates to be deleted and have never logged back into that part of the site over frustration.

I can put the same effort into examples on my own blog and not have to worry about that they will not be vandalized to incorrect balls of mud and attributed to me.

#### Here is the problem:

My examples had lots of upvotes when they are were correct, and they still have those upvotes with all the edits that make them incorrect now.

In the end I just requested all the examples deleted because they are now just wrong, and I got tired of the [Sisyphean](https://www.google.com/search?q=define%20sisyphean)<sub>[1](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Sisyphus)</sub> task of correcting them over and over and over.

My main personal concern is: I don't want my name and reputation (outside Stack Overflow) tied to incorrect information.

A secondary personal concern is: I don't want the reputation points from incorrect examples, and I don't want to lose reputation points I gained from when they were correct.

This is fundamentally broken, and if documentation stays this way it will get the same reputation that [W3Schools](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/W3Schools) has about providing just plain incorrect information with equal weight as correct information.

#### My Solution:

*Examples should be tied to the original creator and that creator should have unilateral veto over edits by having to approve them before they are public, since the editor is free to create their own example how they would do it.*

## What can we do about repeated edits that make examples incorrect?

Comment: There are a handful of proposals out there which involve changing the way reviews are done so that they can be reviewed for correctness as well as vandalism, which would be good things to support.

Comment: Could you link to one or two of these edits so the rest of us can more easily look them over?

Comment: @zer00ne it's not a mythology reference, it's just a figure of speech present in the language.

Comment: @JanDvorak My bad, I thought Mr. Roberson was referring to [Sisyphus](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Sisyphus). He must be referring to [Snuffleupagus](http://muppet.wikia.com/wiki/Mr._Snuffleupagus) of course.

Comment: "My main concern is ..." I do not get the impression the quality of *Documentation* is your main concern.

Comment: @JoshCaswell - I can't they are not available anymore apparently as I requested them to be deleted and I just get an error page on them now. I updated my answer with the main thing I battled with and ultimately abandoned.

Comment: @RadLexus - as I clearly stated my main concern it being associated with crap that I am not responsible for. That keeps me from participating, I am sure others are experiencing similar things in other tags, since I have seen a few complaints about the same problems.

Comment: So you are really not worried about that bad documentation? A more responsible 'tude would be to ask how to prevent such editing in the first place.

Comment: @JanDvorak - it is classical mythology - TLDR: *"In Greek mythology Sisyphus (/ˈsɪsᵻfəs/;[2] Greek: Σίσυφος, Sísuphos) was the king of Ephyra (now known as Corinth). He was punished for his self-aggrandizing craftiness and deceitfulness by being forced to roll an immense boulder up a hill, only to watch it roll back down, repeating this action for eternity. Through the classical influence on modern culture, tasks that are both **laborious** and **futile** are therefore described as **Sisyphean**"*

Comment: I see...  I feel your pain, it's a mess right now with the review queue, too many incorrect edits going through.... It's easy enough to roll-back, but with the current state some examples will need daily rollbacks.  Maybe there should be some way to "protect" examples in order to alleviate the need to constantly monitor the activity tab for bad edits.  Maybe make it so that if an example is "protected", you need at least a bronze tag badge to suggest a change....

Comment: @DanielNugent - it is NOT easy to roll back because after a few edits you can't roll back to where it needs to be because there is a limit to the edit history, you actually have to delete the contents and paste back in the correct code from somewhere else. So I said screw it, too much effort for absolutely nothing.

Comment: @DanielNugent The badge requirement should be the default, not only for protected docs. And maybe it should be a silver or even gold one, not just a bronze one.

Comment: @nwp I'm in full agreement there..... I think that all reviewers should at least have a bronze badge in the tag as well.  It's crazy how many bad edits are going though at the moment......

Comment: One of the problems in documentation is that original author is not notified when someone tries to make the change. I have similar story, with dozen of edits that added very little to the example. Fortunately, they didn't make it incorrect but if I had known about some changes I would try to reject them at least.

Comment: @DalijaPrasnikar You can reject from the queue? I've got [this bug](http://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/334349/812149) that won't let me reject... all I can do is sit by while the robots Approve blatant plagiarism. I've flagged a few cases for moderator attention, but the flags aren't handled yet.

Comment: @S.L.Barth Yes, I can reject from the queue.

Comment: @DalijaPrasnikar OK, thanks. So the bug does not affect all users. I'll point it out on the question I linked; hopefully it'll help SO find the cause.

Comment: What happens when the original creator doesn't know much about the subject and the example count has reached the point where new examples can't be created?

Comment: @JoeW - That is a different problem and also what down votes are for. You can delete vote a question/answer on the main site, why not be able to do the same thing to an example.

Comment: I would consider it a worse problem as the information is still bad and now it is even harder to get it corrected.

Comment: Sooo apt description of the current situation... Stuff like the [Array topic](http://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/333476/1667004), and then now the [completely](http://meta.stackoverflow.com/a/334481/1667004) [crazy](http://meta.stackoverflow.com/a/334526/1667004) review queue... I'm waiting how things will turn out - until then, I'm just checking the review queue for Rejects (all those will be robo-accepted by careless idiots anyway), and try and reverse the edits...

Comment: I don't comment often about this topic because I think I'm biased but -- I now honestly believe Documentation is a misguided attempt at centralizing out the competition. Problem is, under our current social model, it won't work. At all. We will only get plagiarism and review drones, the Q/A side will suffer from it, and centralizing content away from competition is a bad idea anyway -- you *need* them to remain around so you can compare against them and show off how awesome you are.

Comment: Your solution would work if docs was like normal SO. However, the entire concept of docs is that you don't own the post in any special way. So they were never **Your** examples to begin with.

Comment: I'm not saying I don't agree though - I do. The one example I actually completly rewrote has since been edited and now won't compile for some of its snippetsc

Comment: Basically you're posting exceptionally clever examples. And they are destroyed by hordes of people who simply are not clever and want to "fix" it with [dumb code](http://www.oracle.com/technetwork/articles/java/devinsight-1-139780.html) that their inexperienced minds can grasp. I guess one thing to learn from that is: in the site's current state, donate dumb code.

Comment: @Gimby - not clever, idiomatic correct that are actually kind of basic correct practices and they are butchered by illiterates that should not be allowed behind the keyboard. There is nothing *clever* about what I contributed, it is all standard idiomatic correct code that was replaced with *clever* attempts that were stylistic at best that broke the example. Where *clever* here is a pejorative as you incorrectly try to apply to my contribution.

Comment: @JarrodRoberson I guess we have different definitions of the word clever, I thought I was being complimentary and supportive of your plea. I guess not, carry on.

Comment: The use of [*clever code*](https://www.google.com/webhp?sourceid=chrome-instant&rlz=1C1CHBF_enUS696US696&ion=1&espv=2&ie=UTF-8#q=what%20is%20clever%20code) has been derogatory ever since I first read it 30+ years ago on a BBS. It has never been a compliment.Sorry that that is just the way it is.

Comment: Reposting [this comment of mine](http://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/331841/can-i-replace-a-w3schools-link-by-another-authoritative-reference#comment380292_331841): "I actually think W3Schools is more reliable than Stack Overflow Documentation itself. Yes, that's how bad I think the current state of Documentation is [...]: **I'd rather quote a statement from W3Schools that I know is correct than Documentation**."

Comment: And I suspect this question will become very relevant, very soon: [Are questions whose research is primarily based on Documentation on-topic?](http://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/330187/are-questions-whose-research-is-primarily-based-on-documentation-on-topic)

Comment: @JarrodRoberson: All idioms worth using started out as someone's "clever" idea. People thought C++'s STL was "too clever" too. They thought the same thing about metaprogramming and so forth. Eventually though, if the idea is at all good, then "cleverness" gives way to familiarity and idiomaticness. Look at Google's garbage C++ guidelines to see what happens when you don't modernize your idioms.

Comment: I'd be far more concerned that the wrong information exists than about any "rep" I'm getting from it, but yes.

Comment: I would further warn about asserting that your examples are the only possible correct examples, and that other reviewers are "unqualified" to change them. While you may well be correct in this case, that's a very dangerous mindset. It's the same sort of mindset that leads to people writing answers as comments because they cannot believe they would ever be wrong and need downvoting; they're the "qualified" ones, right?! We need better peer review but that cannot be one person dictating what is "correct" and "incorrect"

Comment: @BalusC I'd say start with bronze badge holders and see if that doesn't solve the issue well enough. Or let example creators benefit from a tiered 'protection' level. Users with a gold badge who make an example must be reviewed by silver badge-holders or better, and users with a bronze or silver badge have to be reviewed by a bronze badge-holder or better. My thinking is that gold badge-users tend to make more complex/high-level examples due to their expertise and deep understanding, so raise the bar on who can review their work.

Comment: @LightnessRacesinOrbit - this has nothing to do with *mindset* or *hubris*, it has everything to do with **breaking working code because you don't understand why you are breaking it, even when it is explained in great detail why not to keep changing it back**. If people break an example, and the more and more people come back and rebreak it the same way or worse like adding commentary in that is empirically incorrect, that is just a broken model. How can anyone trust anything if the most basic things are wrong?

Comment: @JarrodRoberson: I don't know :( That's why I think the feature is a fundamentally flawed concept.

Comment: I just wonder - are there enough badge holders actually using Documentation for the idea of limiting to badge holders having any chance of making things better? I get the idea that most people who are worth their weight on SO are not touching it with a ten-foot pole...

Comment: #Gimby - are you dead on the money, and here is the irony, there will be a bunch of gold badge holders that get their rep from Documentation that have no business having the badges. Rep has been diluted from what it meant 7 years ago to the point where it is meaningless other than giving you privileges on the site. Pretty soon it will not mean anything relative to the site as well.

Comment: Yes! Yes! Yes! :D

Comment: In a nutshell, this is why I don't participate in Documentation.

Comment: Lol. Documentation fails

Answer (score 58, accepted):

That looks like a particularly stark example of a general problem that SO has. The fundamental idea of SO was that it would be a repository of answers from experts. But experts are rare, so we instead have vast numbers of non experts answering vast numbers of craps beginners questions. The flaw here is, I think, that the system does not actually value the contributions of experts more highly than those of non experts, so the experts can always be outvoted.

Comment: Who gets to decide which people are "experts" and how do you solve the problem that "experts" are not automatically right about everything? Of course, SO uses the least-evil method of "reputation" to get a vague notion of who's been the most "right" in the past, and we can only decide who was most "right" by polling the community for opinions via votes. Beyond that, you're stuck with accepting CVs for credentials and then just hoping that a degree in X or Y years in Z industry also somehow equates to always being right.

Comment: _(cont.)_ Having worked in the past (fortunately) with someone who declared 30-years prior experience I can tell you that this metric means _nothing_ on its own. I also once saw a book author and professor on SO asserting that operator precedence and expression evaluation order are the same thing. This guy's still out there "teaching" people. It sucks. :(

Comment: @LightnessRacesinOrbit We already have means for classifying experts: reputation and badges.

Comment: Yes, I said that. It's the "least-evil" method. It is certainly highly flawed, though.

Comment: @LightnessRacesinOrbit: Voting, feedback and incremental improvement seem to be working pretty well for main SO. Either the post author is active and will respond to improvement suggestions, or the author is gone but subsequent edits can improve things, or the answer gets downvoted. "Experts" don't have to be right, but they serve an important role in providing the "raw material" of SO. I cannot see any corresponding mechanic for Documentation, alas. (I've been wanting to contribute but feel hopelessly lost.)

Comment: Totally agree, in fact this is something I went into war over when Pet.se was launched. The internet has become a means to dissolve wisdom and truth as popular opinion runs rampant and takes it's place.

Answer (score 27):

> My Solution:
>
> *Examples should be tied to the original creator and that creator should have unilateral veto over edits by having to approve them before they are public, since the editor is free to create their own example how they would do it.*

While I agree with your problem description, I don't second your solution. Two questions highlighting my concerns:

- What if the example is *plain wrong* in the first revision, and OP vetoes all changes?
- What happens if the author disappears, retires from using the site, or *dies*, IRL?

> #### What can we do about repeated edits that make examples incorrect?

I'd say, before accepting, there should be a voting phase for the **edits** - and not the examples, after the edits. Accepting edits should then be done manually...

This does have a lot of questions I don't feel experienced enough to answer... Some of those:

- **What if someone "steals" an edit?** The bad guy downvotes the original, copies the content, and now he is 1 vote better by standing at 0... (maybe if someone votes, should not propose changes?)
- it should be possible to accept multiple edits in one "transaction". Lets say, an example has 3 edits, all worthy, but having overlapping content - making it impossible to apply all the changes at once automatically. This would require a **manual** merging (takes effort!) step from someone willing and able...
- The manual merging requires someone apt for the task - [what would be the criteria](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/a/334481/1667004)?  What about low intensity tags?

Consequently, rep awards should be applied based on votes on the edits after being accepted. It could even be as high as +10 for each upvote - as this would be only a one-time cash-out when the edit would be accepted.

Then I think the reward for upvoting an example could even be 0. (This would mean that with time, the examples would get ordered by how frequently they are found useful in contrast to the other)

Comment: Good point.  Maybe a 7-day veto window before an edit appears?  Or veto powers only keep working when the user has visited the site recently?  Maybe have a configurable level of protection on a per-example basis?  (i.e. people keep messing up this example, so I'm going to protect it with a 7-day approval window).  re: if the example is wrong and OP won't change it, obviously that's what downvotes (and the visible change-request flag they leave) are for.  There are problems, but many of them are solvable.  It might be overall better than what we have now.

Comment: @PeterCordes Good point with protecting - at least the concept is already part of how SO works. If an example brings in a lot of low quality edits, it could be protected - and then only "a select few" could approve edits. That could work.

Comment: "*What if the example is plain wrong in the first revision, and OP vetoes all changes?*" downvote it and move on.

Comment: @null could be OK, but given that the number of examples is limited per topic, this could mean a dead-end. Of course, after some time and a zillion downvotes, some mod intervention would finally end the stance... But I still say, the votes should be on the edits, and not the result.

Answer (score 18):

This is exactly the reason I will not contribute anything to the Documentation until it's fixed. My examples haven't been butchered as thoroughly as yours seem to have been, but several people have "contributed" trivial "stylistic" changes that I dislike. One person even introduced a blatant typo in the title a far as I'm concerned, but attempts to fix this were rejected as "too minor".

Here's the thing: **I** wrote it, **I** spent time on it, **I** did all the work on it, so who exactly are **you** to  make these trivial changes, hm?

It's not that I don't appreciate contributions or fixes to my examples (or answers, for that matter); quite the opposite! I started contributing to wikis years ago precisely *because* I like the feedback that I get, and I'm very grateful to some people for rewriting some of what I wrote (because it's so much better). But constantly correcting non-contributing trivial changes gets very tiresome very fast and is an uphill battle.

From Jon Ericson's answer it seems that Documentation is envisioned as a Wiki:

> What we are banking on is that making it easy for users to fix bad content (AKA, the Wikipedia strategy) will mitigate the problem.

Let me relate some of my experiences with such wikis:

I once spent several hours in an article, and was rather happy with the end result. Another editor comes along and messes up the layout of the photos and changes the tone of it so that it looks more like an "attack piece" rather than "nuanced explanation". I strongly dislike these changes. This editor has no domain knowledge on the topic, and insists these changes *need* to be made and that I do not own the article.

Another example: I once spent several *dozens* of hours on a lengthy article and an editor added a paragraph that I feel is a grossly out-of-context quote to the point that I cannot call it anything other than a lie.

In both cases there were *also* some good contributions from other people, but it's not as if "one good contribution" equals "one bad contribution". In both cases (and in some others) I very much regret writing anything, and given the choice would rather see it deleted since they've been transformed into something I am uncomfortable with and have no desire contributing to.

Stack Overflow is not exactly like Wikipedia or other wikis, so the above experiences are not entirely fair, but there is a fundamental problem with wikis; yeah, anyone can come along and make it better, but this also means the anyone can come along and fuck it up − as has happened here.

---

The "Wikipedia approach" is great for writing in *quantity*, but it doesn't work very well for *quality*. The English Wikipedia currently boasts 5,242,770 articles, and that is an impressive number. Some of these articles are quite nice, but many of them are not. And more than a few of them are rather shit. In my observation there's quite a strong correlation between the complexity of a topic and the quality of its article on it: the more complex, the worse the article is. This makes sense, because anyone can write Wikipedia articles about Pokemon and Star Trek, but writing about complex topics such as science, health, religion, etc. is much more difficult, and often requires quite a bit of in-depth knowledge (and not some random person with a search engine).

Eventually a bad article may turn into something decent by the "anyone can edit approach", but usually it doesn't. Most of the time when something gets fixed it's because a single knowledgeable person takes interest and the time to clean up the mess. "Hamlet by thousands of monkeys" may work eventually, but it takes a long time and is horribly inefficient. Give the monkeys a banana and just get Shakespeare to write it.

---

Doing this full-on Wiki seems like a terrible idea to me, but the wiki features obviously *are* useful − as they are in Q&A − and some balance needs to be found − as there is in Q&A. There needs to be someone to say *"no, this is not a good change, sorry"*. The current review systems works very mediocre at best on the Q&A, and I see no reason why it should fare better on Documentation, plus it's harder to fix bad reviews on documentation (I can fix bad edit reviews on my own answers, but not my own examples).

There are more problems with the "anyone can edit" Wiki approach, by the way, but I'll save those for another time ;-)

Comment: "*it doesn't work very well for quality*" Wikipedia has pretty decent quality. At one point in time, it was determined that errors in Wikipedia articles were about as common as errors in regular encyclopedias (for similar articles). I have no idea how true that is nowadays, but it was true for a time. The problem with Docs.SO is not that it follows the Wikipedia model. It's that it follows it *terribly*. Its structure is hard-coded, unlike MediaWiki which is free-form. Its structural elements like "topic" are il-defined. And so forth.

Comment: "*Here's the thing: I wrote it, I spent time on it, I did all the work on it, so who exactly are you to make these trivial changes, hm?*" Who are you to say that they shouldn't be made? You willingly choose to contribute to a collaboratively edited article. You have no more right to it than the next person. And the only people who are functional in that environment are those who are willing to let little things go. Who are willing to surrender the need for control and ownership of their content.

Comment: @NicolBolas "Wikipedia has pretty decent quality." because they don't give you imaginary internet points.

Comment: The problem here is the viewpoint that comes through in the language you've used: "My examples haven't been butchered as thoroughly as yours seem to have been, but several people have "contributed" trivial "stylistic" changes that I dislike." Documentation, examples, topics, etc. aren't *yours*. Approve edits if you think they improve something, reject them if they don't or if they harm something. I understand there's a disconnect here with *perceived* ownership, since your picture is displayed next to an example you've edited, but it doesn't change the facts of "real" ownership.

Comment: @TylerH So if I go around and change all the C-braces to my personal preferred location, or change variable names to my personally preferred
 naming style then that's okay?

Comment: @TylerH - regardless of "ownership", perception or not, correct things are being made into **incorrect things* that have peoples names attached to them and that ignores the main complaint, they are being made incorrect or vandalized a rate that "reject things" is flat out impossible. That is why I am got what I could deleted completely and have formally requested that my account be disassociated with everything on Documentation as per Jon's advice and guidance. Enjoy watching Rome burn.

Comment: @NicolBolas - *those who are willing to let little things go* making something patently and empirically incorrect is **not a little thing**. Making it an Sysphipean task to correct since your name is tied to it, make it where the knowledgeable are unwilling to take part. Enjoy the downward spiral of entropy that Documentation is on.And remember that I said this first *"It will drag down the reputation of the quality of SO, so suddenly and so quietly that it will be next to impossible to correct without removing the Documentation portion completely or make SO as relevant as MySpace is today"*

Comment: @JarrodRoberson: "*making something patently and empirically incorrect is not a little thing.*" The point of my response was that your experiences with Wikis was not about "empirically incorrect" things. Someone changed the formatting of an article; *big deal*. Someone "changed the tone" of the article; *so what*? Unless that content is *demonstrably wrong* (or for Wikipedia, is not verifiable), you have no right to refuse it. That is the attitude you need to have for collaborative editing to work. And it's not everyone's cup of tea, but that hasn't stopped Wikipedia from working.

Comment: @Carpetsmoker: "*So if I go around and change all the C-braces to my personal preferred location, or change variable names to my personally preferred naming style then that's okay?*" OK in the sense that you are *capable* of doing it. Just as you could do so with every question and answer on SO if you have editing privileges. Do we like such things? No.

Comment: @JarrodRoberson: "*Enjoy the downward spiral of entropy that Documentation is on.*" Oh please. Docs.SO has been on a "downward spiral of entropy" since it was *conceived*. The very foundational ideas of it were poorly conceived; nothing good comes from such a thing. I believe in collaborative editing as a means to create good information. I don't believe in Docs.SO, not because it uses collaborative editing, but because nobody has any idea how it's supposed to work at all.

Comment: @NicolBolas Note that I, for one, am *not* against "collaborative editing" as such. I'm merely against the the idea of "anyone can edit anything". There are many more forms that collaborative editing can take.

Comment: @NicolBolas - you are conflating MY question and comments with Carpetsmokers side comments about their personal experiences and how they relate to my question. The Topic here is Documentation Examples that are either correct or incorrect, when something crashes or doesn't compile or generates the wrong output that is inarguably incorrect.

Comment: You put my name in this *@JarrodRoberson: "making something patently and empirically incorrect is not a little thing." The point of my response was that your experiences with Wikis was not about "empirically incorrect" things.* that is conflating what they wrote with *my experiences*, if this is not what you meant then you need to fix it. As it reads now you are conflating what they wrote with me.

Comment: @JarrodRoberson: Sorry. It's a thread from two days ago; I hadn't re-read the particulars of it.

Comment: None of the wiki's I use have a game mechanic of imaginary internet points you can earn that encourages you to just amass points regardless of the benefit to the system as a whole.

Answer (score 8):

We can disassociate examples from your account, which should allow you to avoid having your name attached to code you don't want your name attached to and avoid getting reputation that you don't feel is warranted. The most expedient way to do that is to use the contact form at the bottom of the page.

---

To loop back to the bulk of your question, I do think that there is a serious risk that Documentation (or at least particular tags within Documentation) could be the source of false or misleading information. What we are banking on is that making it easy for users to fix bad content (AKA, the Wikipedia strategy) will mitigate the problem. I won't say "solve" because the problem is a moving target. No documentation is perfect and the best we can hope for is "generally useful".

W3Schools is an interesting contrast. According to their [about us page](http://www.w3schools.com/about/default.asp):

> ## You Can Help
>
> Many people are working very hard to make W3Schools interesting, useful, and correct.
>
> If you find an error, or a broken link, please tell us about it.
>
> Use the link "REPORT ERROR" at the bottom of each page.

That's a classic [pre-Wikipedia approach](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/a/330003/1438). Instead of letting users solve the problems directly, they funnel everything through a black box.

But giving users easy access to change Documentation (which wasn't really the case until the [review queue](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/334404/documentation-update-september-12th)) is only a necessary condition for success. As you described, we have a problem that there's no easy way to track previous edits and talk about why particular examples should be structured in one way or another. At the moment, you can't tell future editors why your code structure is necessary and so people make the same mistakes over and over.

We are working on a solution (a [discussion section](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/334404/documentation-update-september-12th)) but that's going to take some time to get implemented and working well. I don't fault you for preferring your blog as a platform for examples. Blogging is an established method of publication in sharp contrast to a beta feature like Documentation.

However, I do think there is a hack to get around the problem you describe: **use prose, comments, and/or the Remarks section to explain the problem**. You can even include a counter-example to show the pitfalls to using the broken coding method. One pleasant side-effect of this technique is that it will educate future readers (and potential editors!) about the problem you are highlighting here on meta. In addition, that information will be at hand for *reviewers* of changes that screw up an example.

(Note: I haven't gone searching for the example you mentioned, so it's possible you have done this already. A link in the question would really help to have a sensible discussion.)

Comment: the problem is you have to make it **easy for people to fix problems** and **hard for people to cause problems**. Right now it is the opposite. **easy to cause problems** while **Sisyphean effort to fix**. None of those proposed things will fix the problem or get someone like me to contribute anymore.  Examples should be tied to the original creator and that creator should have unilateral veto over edits, since the editor is free to create their own example how they would do it.

Comment: @JarrodRoberson: That's a valid model and a very sensible one. But it's not the model we are building. For better or worse, the die is cast and we are pursuing collaboratively edited documentation.

Comment: I appreciate what you are trying to do, but I am sure you are losing lots of experienced people with that approach. Not all contributions are equally valid. There are more unqualified editors and approvers than there are qualified, and that ratio is never going to improve and will most likely decline rapidly, thus this post. But then again, many former co-workers refer to me as  [Cassandra](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cassandra) after their projects/companies failed just like I predicted. My experience tells me it has already failed.

Comment: @JarrodRoberson: Noted.

Comment: @JarrodRoberson What you're looking for is SO itself with self-answered questions. That's the more reasonable to way to "retain control" of content. Either way, I'm with you along with the crowd. Documentation is doomed to fail if it can't solve the signal-to-noise ratio with unqualified contributors.

Comment: @JonEricson - `/predicted/predicted and was ignored/` is how I earned that moniker.

Comment: @Mysticial - I don't even click on that button anymore. It has already failed personally for me.

Comment: @JarrodRoberson I won't say that examples *need* to have a "creator" or "owner". But I agree that *somebody* (not necessarily singular) who is technically qualified needs to be in charge acting as a moderator. It's just that the creator is usually the most suitable person for that role. For starters it might be worth a shot at giving gold badge holders that role.

Comment: @JarrodRoberson: I got the reference. I can't speak for the rest of the team, but I would prefer to fail at something different and potentially revolutionary than succeed at doing the thing we've been doing for about as long as computer programming has been practiced. Monumental challenges await Documentation, so there's a non-trivial chance it will fail.  (And when it does, we'll probably be compelled to revert to the tried-and-true authorial control model.) I'm listening to your prediction, but at this point it isn't something we are going to act on.

Comment: Nobody says it's the only way to fix it. You could make it _harder_ to review badly (i.e. without consequences), and thus removing the _easy to cause problems_ part. A discussion section is only helpful when people are unsure (as they only then look there). That's not the point. Relatively strict audits and eventually giving 1k+ rep users only 1.5 votes and 10k+ rep users 2 votes. That'll automatically involve more eyes having a look at it. And … only needing half of votes to reject something (yes, that will mean a 10k+ rep user may singlehandedly reject everything).

Comment: But currently you're just opening the Box of Pandora a bit more with the review queues. Before the queue, I feel like less low quality/partially incorrect posts passed, at least in php tag. Now, it's becoming somewhat as bad as e.g. java tag. … Not that the queue is bad per se… It's just too unfiltered contributors, without restrictions… Hadn't you already looked at implementing the audits _yesterday_? @JonEricson

Comment: @bwoebi: We are still planning on audits. And we have other arrows in the quiver if that isn't sufficient. Don't forget: quicker reviews makes rollbacks dramatically faster too. (And as of the reputation changes yesterday, those contributions no longer pay out reputation.) At any rate, the problem described here _sounds like disagreement_ rather than low quality or whatnot. (And as always, this discussion is **immeasurably less valuable without a link**. It's easy enough to say everything is terrible, but there should be plenty of evidence if true.)

Comment: I have the silver badge (even gold) in php, so I can easily rollback everything. It just is somewhat annoying to have each day go to the approved reviews list and re-review every single item again; (e.g. very recently: http://stackoverflow.com/documentation/review/changes/96227 - had already an approve vote and would certainly have passed if it weren0't for me…) — It would be tremendously easier if at very least basic things like plagiarism etc. would have been checked (e.g. http://stackoverflow.com/documentation/review/changes/95012) … _just_ checking quality is less work.

Comment: Thanks for the disassociation guidance. I think all the things were deleted already but I sent the email just to make sure.

Comment: If it was possible to vote on edits after they happened, that might give some sort of way of measuring contributor edit quality. Then you can also do  tag-rep vs edit correlation and see which revisions are the most respected. Being able to down-vote an edit without downvoting the example might encourage better representation.  "preferred edit by authors" etc.

Comment: the audits are fundamentally broken on the main site, the review queues are just a sisyphean task as well. why review things that should have never been allowed in the first place when you can just write crap answers to the endless stream of dupes and gain more rep. audits won't do anything but drive away and punish those that do it regularly by banning them for doing it. that is another thing I abandoned long ago. SOCVR exists because the reviews/audits are broken and ineffective.

Comment: "we are pursuing collaboratively edited documentation" By whom? People who know what they're talking about, people who *don't* but suffer from the Dunning-Kruger effect, or people who *knowingly don't* and just want dibs on having contributed to, well, something? I suspect it's all three, since I remember the launch banner saying "Whether you're a beginner or an experienced developer, you *can* contribute."

Comment: @bwoebi `just checking quality is less work` - this is why I was trying to come up with [a solution for this one](http://meta.stackoverflow.com/a/334526/1667004)...

Comment: @BoltClock: Yes. All three of those categories and several more: people learning (or relearning) the topic, people who are good at editing, and so on. The bet we are making is that openness will allow Documentation to converge over time to be more helpful to a wider variety of users. We haven't provided you all with the tools you all need to do that quite yet. It's not an easy problem to solve—perhaps impossible. But we think the end result will be well worthwhile if successful.

Comment: This is the only reason I upvoted this; *We can disassociate examples from your account, which should allow you to avoid having your name attached to code you don't want your name attached to and avoid getting reputation that you don't feel is warranted. The most expedient way to do that is to use the contact form at the bottom of the page.* The rest I disagree with fundamentally, but this answered my question indirectly.

Comment: None of the wiki's I use have a game mechanic of imaginary internet points you can earn that encourages you to just amass points regardless of the benefit to the system as a whole.

Comment: @Then maybe the solution is to remove gamification altogether. If it works for Wikipedia, why can't it for Docs?