# Reject documentation changes if the change reason / comment is not clear enough

Tags: discussion, documentation, documentation-review

Based on [this](https://stackoverflow.com/documentation/review/changes/107138) documentation review, I want to initiate some discussion. In this review we have the following,

> Deletion of a topic,  with the reason of `Handling improvement requests`

The change (the deletion of the topic) was accepted, however I personally disagree, because it is not clear to me why, in the first it should be deleted. To tell the truth I am not familiar with the topic, so I do not know if the topic was too specific and this is why it was deleted.

The problems I see here are the following,

- The `Handling improvement requests` as a deletion reason is too general. I was unable to find this `Improvement Request`, is it really there? Maybe it was [dismissed](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/330041/in-documentation-someone-should-have-to-provide-a-reason-for-dismissing-a-reques?rq=1) and that is why it was not visible during the review, which misleading in my opinion.
- A comment `I am not able to see any improvement request for this. Please elaborate!` (of me), it was never answered

There is [this](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/330525/documentation-change-rejections-could-use-improvement) related resource, where in summary it says that if the review reason is not clear enough, the user should talk in comment or in chat. However, in the case above, the user did not care to answer the comment.

Is there a way to **force**

- Users answering, the comments / questions of a reviewer
- Using more descriptive review reason

Comment: I can’t see one in the old view either: http://stackoverflow.com/documentation/proposed/changes/107138?noredirect=1

Comment: Looks to me like it is part of the other side of the coin: robo reviewers, which  are rampant in Documentation. It wouldn't be a problem that poor suggestions are made if they wouldn't be accepted almost without resistance.

Comment: @DanielNugent As I said I am not familiar with the topic, so I just skipped this one. My 'issue' here was, that wasn't a brief explanation on why this was deleted and the so called Improvement request was not visible.

Comment: Yes, I agree that for all deletion edits, the reason should be stated clearly, and that was not done in this case.....